# Static imports in swift

Tags: swift, static

In java you can do `import static MyClass` and you'll be able to access the static methods of `MyClass` without having to prepend them with the class name:

`myMethod()` instead of `MyClass.myMethod()`

Is there a way to do this in swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don´t think you can import a static class like Java, it´s a traditional static in Swift where you call it by class name + variable/function.

```
class  MyClass {
    static let baseURL = "someURl"

    static func myMethod() {

    }
}
```

`MyClass.baseURL` or `MyClass. myMethod`.

What you can do is to add a `typealias` to make an alias for your Static class.

```
private typealias M = MyClass
```

And then use the following: `M.baseURL` or `M.myMethod`.

Comment: You're right, but it *is* possible to make things a little less verbose by adding a `private typealias M = MyClass`, which lets you call the statics with `M.myMethod()`. IMHO, that's almost *better* than Java, because it still indicates that the method is defined somewhere else, not in the source file you're currently editing.

Comment: Indeed you can @NRitH. Added it as an example to OP.